# Get time taken to login successfully into an application and store it into database

Tags: java, mysql, moodle

i'm using `Moodle` (E-Learning Application) as an application to be monitored. I want to get the time taken for user to login into `Moodle` and store it into mysql database. So my question is how to get the time taken to login and store it into mysql database?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "time taken to log in?", because I can think of three different definitions: 1. The time a user needs from loading the site to filling out a login form once, no matter if the data is correct. 2. The time it takes to fill out the login form correctly. 3. The time it takes from clicking "submit" to actually getting access.

Comment: Consider using the [logs from Moodle](https://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Logs) to find out the login time. Storing into a database is a process you can learn more about [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html), among other places.

Comment: @Silverclaw i mean the 3rd option..time taken after clicking "submit" or "log in" button and then get access..

Comment: @kirkpatt thank you for the link..i will look for the solution in the link after this..